# Preventing Sublime to Search Automatically

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am working on a XML document that contains huge amounts of data. Whenever I want to make a search regarding to a specific keyword (let's assume a 4-letter-word) by typing just the first letter, the sublimetext 2 automatically stars searching thus freezes for a fair amount of time which is quite disturbing.

Is there any way for me to prevent sublimetext doing so? For example, it may wait for me till I press the "enter", or it may start searching after 3 letters are typed.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The Sublime Text find panel has a little toggle button called "Highlight matches".  When this is enabled, Sublime searches instantly as you type.  When it is disabled, Sublime won't search until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click one of the Find buttons.

Here is a screenshot of ST3 showing the button:

- Build 3105, Default theme: [image: sublime text find panel - highlight matches toggle button ST3105]
- Build 3156, Adaptive theme with orange accent: [image: sublime text find panel - highlight matches toggle button ST3156]

Comment: But the 'Highlight' doesn't work on regex, such as '\b', which will  be highlighted in vscode.